# transform columns value into an ordered other dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello everyone I need help in order to transform columns value into an ordered other dataframe

Here is the **df1**

```
  Groups       Species Values Clusters
1     G1 Cattus_cattus     10 C1,C2,C3
2     G1 Cattus_cattus     10    C7,C8
3     G1 Cattus_cattus     10       C9
4     G2   Canis_lupus      2    C4,C5
5     G2   Canis_lupus      2      C24
6     G3  Griseus_lupa     90  C22,C78
7     G4  Griseus_lupa     89      C19
```

and from the **df1$Groups** I would like to create an ordered **df2** with 4 empty rows (where colnames ae the **df1$Groups** values ordered as in **df1** such as

`df2`:

```
  rows C1 C2 C3 C7 C8 C9 C4 C5 C24 C22 C78 C19
1 row1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2 row2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3 row3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
4 row3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
5 row4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

does someone have an idea please ?

**df1 data**

```
structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Canis_lupus", "Cattus_cattus", 
"Griseus_lupa"), class = "factor"), Values = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 
2L, 2L, 90L, 89L), Clusters = structure(c(1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 
3L, 2L), .Label = c("C1,C2,C3", "C19", "C22,C78", "C24", "C4,C5", 
"C7,C8", "C9"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using the mighty **data.table** package. I am not sure I understand the purpose of such operation, but I think the code below solves your problem.

```r
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

df1 = structure(
  list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L ), 
                          .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"), class = "factor"), 
       Species = structure(c(2L, 
                             2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), 
                           .Label = c("Canis_lupus", "Cattus_cattus", 
                                      "Griseus_lupa"), class = "factor"), 
       Values = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 90L, 89L), 
       Clusters = structure(c(1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L), 
                            .Label = c("C1,C2,C3", "C19", "C22,C78", "C24", "C4,C5", 
                                       "C7,C8", "C9"), class = "factor")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -7L))

setDT(df1)
newcols = unlist(str_split(df1$Clusters, ","))
Nrows = uniqueN(df1$Groups)
Ncols = length(newcols)

df2 = data.table( rows = paste0( "row", 1L:Nrows ) )

df2[ , (newcols) := NA ]
df2
#>    rows C1 C2 C3 C7 C8 C9 C4 C5 C24 C22 C78 C19
#> 1: row1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 2: row2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 3: row3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 4: row4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>